# What does the swift keyword Wrapped mean in the Optional extension?

Tags: swift

What does the swift keyword Wrapped mean in the Optional extension?

```
extension Optional {
    func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> U?) -> U? {
        guard let x = self else { return nil }
        return transform(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In extensions, the generic parameters of the type that you are extending can be referenced by just writing their simple names, and notice that [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) is a generic type.

```
@frozen enum Optional<Wrapped>
```

So `Wrapped` in the function declaration refers to the generic parameter declared there.

As you may know, optional types are usually written as `T?` (where `T` is some type), which is a syntactic sugar for `Optional<T>`. For example, `Int?` is the same as `Optional<Int>`, and `String?` is the same as `Optional<String>`, etc.

In other words, `Wrapped` basically just means the type that precedes the `?`, whatever that may be. If you have a `String?` (aka `Optional<String>`), then the signature of `flatMap` for that would be:

```
func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (String) -> U?) -> U?
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no keyword "Wrapped." This is a type parameter. This is similar to runtime parameters. If you see:

```
func f(x: Int) { ... }
```

`x` is not a keyword. It's just a parameter name. In the same way, Optional is defined as:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped>
```

"Wrapped" is just the type parameter passed to Optional. So in this extension:

```
func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> U?) -> U? {
```

"Wrapped" just refers to whatever Optional is wrapping.